# Convert color to texture in Unreal 5.3

Tags: unreal

I have a blg file containing a building, using the advanced show options and checking the 'vertex color' setting I was able to see the building with color.

[image]

But if I put a camera in front and try to see it , the building appears with no color.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? perhaps converting the color to texture? so that in the rendering of the scene the building appears with the correct colors.